# Grouping CSV Rows By The Names of Users

Tags: python, csv, grouping

I have a table on Python with the following data from a CSV:

```
| subscriberKey | Name | Job
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| 123@yahoo.com    | Brian | Computer Tech|
| example@gmail.com   | Brian          | Sales|
| someone@google.com |Gabby |Sales|
| testinge@sendesk.com |Gabby |Marketing|
| sandbox@aol.com |Tyler | Porter |
```

I want to be able to group the data by the Name and have all of the other cells come with it.
It should end up looking like this.

```
| subscriberKey | Name | Job
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| 123@yahoo.com    | Brian | Computer Tech|
| example@gmail.com   | Brian          | Sales|

| subscriberKey | Name | Job
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| someone@google.com |Gabby |Sales|
| testinge@sendesk.com |Gabby |Marketing|

| subscriberKey | Name | Job
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| sandbox@aol.com |Tyler | Porter |
```

Furthermore, I want to create a new csv file for every table that is created. Can anyone help? I have tried to loop it through but have failed too many times. I am currently back to the base and only have the file propagting in its normal table. Can anyone help?

```
    import csv

f = open('work.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
  print (row)
```

Comment: Try reading the lines from the file and add them to a list. You can then sort the list, read through it in the order you want, and write to another file.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to group variables based on a certain key (the name in this case) a hashmap is usually a good data structure to try.

As a general solution for future readers:

1. Create an empty dictionary.
2. Choose the key that you want to group your data.
3. Iterate over the data and parse the key and related items.
4. Add the related items to dict[key].

Now each key in dict will have a list of all the items related to it.

---

Tailored more specifically to the OP's question:

```py
import collections

def write_csv(name, lines):
    with open(f"{name}_work.csv", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(','.join(item for item in line))
            f.write('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # LOAD DATA
    with open("work.csv", 'r') as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            lines.append(line.strip('\n').split(','))
    
    # GROUP DATA BY NAME INTO A DICTIONARY
    names = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for email, name, job in lines[1:]:
        names[name].append((email, job))
        
    # WRITE A NEW .csv FILE FOR EACH NAME
    for name in names:
        new_lines = lines[:1]
        for email, job in names[name]:
            new_lines.append([name, email, job])
        write_csv(name, new_lines)
```